# Pythagorean Theorem via Geometric Progression

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, geometric-series, geometric-progressions

[Cut The Kont](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/Proof100.shtml) offers a proof of the Pythagorean Theorem based on a converging geometric series of similar right triangles. The second image on that page ([linked](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/Proof100-2.jpg)) is the most relevant for this question.

It is already know that altitude $h=\frac{ab}{c}$ and that $b_{1}=b\frac{a^{2}}{c^{2}}$. To finish the proof as per this example, I would have to get $\frac{b}{b_{1}}=\frac{b^{2}}{c^{2}}$. Then, by setting $x=\frac{b^{2}}{c^{2}} < 1$ the formula for a geometric series can be applied so that:

> $\displaystyle
> \begin{align} 
> b=b_1+b_2+b_3+\ldots b&=b_1(1+x+x^2+\ldots)\\
> &=b\frac{a^2}{c^2}\cdot\frac{1}{1-b^2/c^2}\\
> &=b\frac{a^2}{c^2-b^2}
> \end{align}$

and $\frac{a^{2}}{c^{2}-b^{2}}=1$

My only issue with this proof is that I cannot get $\frac{b}{b_{1}}=\frac{b^{2}}{c^{2}}$. I have been able to get $\frac{b}{b_{1}}=\frac{c^{2}}{b^{2}}$, which does not work with the aforementioned method. Using the image provided, how, if possible, can this be done?

Comment: suppose $\frac{b}{b_{1}}=\frac{b^{2}}{c^{2}}$ is true. then $\frac{c^2}{a^2}=\frac{b^{2}}{c^{2}}$. We will have $c^2=ab$, which is impossible to have such a right triangle